# Вывод данных из NamedQuery

Tags: java, java-ee

Добрый вечер. Не могу разобраться с выводом результатов запросов к БД. Сделал запрос:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Groups.findNames", query = "SELECT g.groupNum, s.fio, s.studentPK.studentId FROM Groups g, Student s WHERE s.studentPK.groupId=g.groupId")})
```

После этого обрабатываю его в Session Bean:

```
public List find1()
{
    Query q=em.createNamedQuery("Groups.findNames");
    List result=q.getResultList();
    return result;
}
```

Дальше через сервлет передаю во вьюху, здесь написать код вьюхи не могу, выкинул сюда http://pastebin.com/G3gdxEKv

И пишет ошибку, что не может найти таких свойств у объекта article. Попробовал ради интереса вывести объекты строкой, получил что-то странное:

> [Ljava.lang.Object;@4165186
> [Ljava.lang.Object;@3a480744
> [Ljava.lang.Object;@67a94417
> [Ljava.lang.Object;@5a55c432

Можете объяснить что это такое и как решить проблему? С джавой работаю пока очень недавно.

Выложил проект на гит, может так легче будет. https://github.com/alex221292/java
Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: Не нашел описания "items="${articles}""?... В выводе Вы получили объекты которые запросили у БД. А зачем Вам StudentPK?